# Unity Game crashing at Launch on iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, unity-game-engine, crash, crash-reports

I run windows and used Macincloud to build my game and it installs fine on devices using testflightapp.com but when ever it starts it shows the unity logo splash then minimizes. My friend was able to get me a crash log but I have no clue in the world how to read it...

I have no clue what is going wrong... runs fine on windows and android...

```
Incident Identifier: 035E3FBC-75D7-4A83-ACFD-BFDBE1B76146
CrashReporter Key:   366e6d2ba3ef9141e57f3cb9bd69c3cf7830efdf
Hardware Model:      iPhone4,1
Process:             kanaji [317]
Path:                /var/mobile/Applications/5B46F2B2-ED6F-4BBA-8D97-ED5156F3F2A1/kanaji.app/kanaji
Identifier:          com.ubersoftech.kanaji
Version:             0.2.4-2 (0.2.4-2)
Code Type:           ARM (Native)
Parent Process:      launchd [1]

Date/Time:           2014-09-10 19:59:30.353 -1000
OS Version:          iOS 7.1.1 (11D201)
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Thread 0 name:  main
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e091f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e73792 pthread_kill + 54
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39db9fd8 abort + 72
3   kanaji                          0x013ab5c0 0x91000 + 20030912
4   kanaji                          0x013c82f8 0x91000 + 20148984
5   libsystem_platform.dylib        0x39e6df90 _sigtramp + 40
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e73792 pthread_kill + 54
7   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39db9fd8 abort + 72
8   kanaji                          0x00da7948 0x91000 + 13723976
9   kanaji                          0x00da295c 0x91000 + 13703516
10  kanaji                          0x00d95350 0x91000 + 13648720
11  Foundation                      0x2f9ad15e __NSFireDelayedPerform + 410
12  CoreFoundation                  0x2ef991b4 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_TIMER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 12
13  CoreFoundation                  0x2ef98dca __CFRunLoopDoTimer + 778
14  CoreFoundation                  0x2ef97166 __CFRunLoopRun + 1206
15  CoreFoundation                  0x2ef01f0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
16  CoreFoundation                  0x2ef01cee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
17  GraphicsServices                0x33e5a65e GSEventRunModal + 134
18  UIKit                           0x3184d168 UIApplicationMain + 1132
19  kanaji                          0x00096c44 0x91000 + 23620
20  kanaji                          0x00096a74 0x91000 + 23156

Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39df6808 kevent64 + 24
1   libdispatch.dylib               0x39d38078 _dispatch_mgr_invoke + 228
2   libdispatch.dylib               0x39d37dfe _dispatch_mgr_thread$VARIANT$mp + 34

Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e09c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70bda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70a94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e09c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70bda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70a94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e09c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70bda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70a94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39df6aa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   kanaji                          0x01492f88 0x91000 + 20979592
2   kanaji                          0x013eeba4 0x91000 + 20306852
3   kanaji                          0x0146ea68 0x91000 + 20830824
4   kanaji                          0x0148ba9c 0x91000 + 20949660
5   kanaji                          0x014a7c38 0x91000 + 21064760
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72916 _pthread_body + 138
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72886 _pthread_start + 98
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39df6aa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   kanaji                          0x00fcdfc8 0x91000 + 15978440
2   kanaji                          0x00fcd6b0 0x91000 + 15976112
3   kanaji                          0x00fce4a4 0x91000 + 15979684
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72916 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72886 _pthread_start + 98
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39df6aa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   kanaji                          0x014faec8 0x91000 + 21405384
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72916 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72886 _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39df6aa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   kanaji                          0x00fcdfc8 0x91000 + 15978440
2   kanaji                          0x00f10a3c 0x91000 + 15202876
3   kanaji                          0x00fce4a4 0x91000 + 15979684
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72916 _pthread_body + 138
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72886 _pthread_start + 98
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 9 name:  com.apple.NSURLConnectionLoader
Thread 9:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39df6a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39df6854 mach_msg + 44
2   CoreFoundation                  0x2ef98896 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 150
3   CoreFoundation                  0x2ef96fbc __CFRunLoopRun + 780
4   CoreFoundation                  0x2ef01f0a CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 518
5   CoreFoundation                  0x2ef01cee CFRunLoopRunInMode + 102
6   Foundation                      0x2f941082 +[NSURLConnection(Loader) _resourceLoadLoop:] + 314
7   Foundation                      0x2f9b6a5a __NSThread__main__ + 1058
8   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72916 _pthread_body + 138
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72886 _pthread_start + 98
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e09c70 __workq_kernreturn + 8
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70bda _pthread_wqthread + 306
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70a94 start_wqthread + 4

Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39df6aa8 semaphore_wait_trap + 8
1   kanaji                          0x01228938 0x91000 + 18446648
2   kanaji                          0x0123d838 0x91000 + 18532408
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72916 _pthread_body + 138
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72886 _pthread_start + 98
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 12:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39df6a58 mach_msg_trap + 20
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39df6854 mach_msg + 44
2   AudioToolbox                    0x2e97d7f6 AURemoteIO::IOThread::Run() + 102
3   AudioToolbox                    0x2e9808dc AURemoteIO::IOThread::Entry(void*) + 4
4   AudioToolbox                    0x2e8bdfc0 CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 208
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72916 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72886 _pthread_start + 98
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 13:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e09544 __semwait_signal + 24
1   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39d7a988 nanosleep + 168
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x39d7a8d6 usleep + 46
3   kanaji                          0x0122868a 0x91000 + 18445962
4   kanaji                          0x0123d822 0x91000 + 18532386
5   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72916 _pthread_body + 138
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72886 _pthread_start + 98
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 14 name:  com.apple.CFSocket.private
Thread 14:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x39e09434 __select + 20
1   CoreFoundation                  0x2ef9c758 __CFSocketManager + 480
2   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72916 _pthread_body + 138
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e72886 _pthread_start + 98
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x39e70aa0 thread_start + 4

Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (32-bit):
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x00000000      r2: 0x00000000      r3: 0x27d70990
    r4: 0x00000006    r5: 0x3bdae18c      r6: 0x00000006      r7: 0x27d70988
    r8: 0x04fede00    r9: 0x39e6df69     r10: 0x00000002     r11: 0x17681260
    ip: 0x00000148    sp: 0x27d7097c      lr: 0x39e73797      pc: 0x39e091f0
  cpsr: 0x00000010

Binary Images:
{Cut to conserve space in post}
```

Comment: See: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/technotes/tn2151/_index.html
You need to "symbolicate" the crash log so you know what method that entry #3 is where your app (kanaji) makes a call to a system framework that eventually ends up crashing. Better yet, get your hands on an iOS device where the crash occurs or try to reproduce the crash, ie install it through testflight.

Comment: I have an iOS device just not a Mac. I will "symbolicate" the crash log!